# Are there axioms in a natural deduction system?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

In the Hilbert system, a proof may include some axioms. In a natural deduction system, it seems no axiom is involved, at least from the examples I read in logic books. So, I wonder how axioms such as those for ZFC play a role in a natural deduction system. Thanks.

Comment: Examples of rules of deduction (i.e. axioms of logic) include the introduction and elimination of various logical operators: $\land, \lor, \implies$, etc.

Comment: A natural deduction system can have axioms. However, in practice they often have a minimal number or no axioms at all. The distinguishing feature is that the rules of inference reflect simple and intuitive patterns of reasoning used by humans for centuries. When using a formal logical system to contruct proves for a mathematical theory, you typically just add on non-logical axioms, including inference rules

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hilbert system and natural deduction can be seen as two "dual" approaches to writing formal proofs. Roughly, when it comes to deriving formulas that are valid in a specific logical system (classical logic, intuitionistic logic, and so on), the Hilbert system has many logical axioms and minimizes the number of inference rules (in the propositional case, the only inference rule is *modus ponens*), while natural deduction only uses inference rules and has no axioms.

In natural deduction, a logical derivation can be represented as a tree-like structure whose leaves $A_1, \dots, A_n$ (except the discharged ones, but let us abstract from that for the moment) are the *assumptions* or *hypotheses*, and whose root $B$ is the *conclusion* or *thesis*.  It means that "from $A_1, \dots, A_n$ one can derive $B$", often noted $A_1, \dots, A_n \vdash B$. If you look at your derivation top-down, you start from the hypotheses $A_1, \dots, A_n$ and you conclude $B$ by only repeatedly using the inference rules of natural deduction (which are syntactical manipulations of the logic symbols$-$connectives and quantifiers$-$occurring in a formula), *without using any axioms*.
The special case $n = 0$ means that $B$ is a *logically valid* formula (also known as a *tautology* in propositional classical logic), which is derived *without any assumptions* (as well as without any axioms): indeed, in the derivation proving $B$, the leaves are not "active" anymore, since all of them are been discharged by inference rules such as $\to_\text{intro}$ occurring in the derivation.
By the way, note that proving $A_1, \dots, A_n \vdash B$ is equivalent to prove $\vdash (A_1 \land \dots \land A_n) \to B$.

What happens when you want to use a formal system to write proofs in a specific mathematical theory (for instance, set theory as axiomatized in ZFC) and not in a purely logical framework? The point is that to formalize a mathematical theory, you have to manipulate non-logical symbols (such as $\in$ in ZFC), and you need to "teach" your formal system$-$which is purely syntactical$-$how to manipulate them. The most natural and common way to do that in a formal system such as Hilbert calculus or natural deduction is to add non-logical axioms that are specific to that mathematical theory (for instance, the axioms of ZFC).
By "non-logical" I mean that the axioms of the mathematical theory are *not* logically valid formulas (otherwise there would be no need to add them) and they talk about basic properties that hold only in that mathematical theory.

In natural deduction, adding axioms means that you add $0$-ary inference rules, that is, inference rules with no premises and whose conclusion is one of the non-logical axioms. This way, a natural deduction derivation within a mathematical theory $\mathcal{T}$ (such as ZFC), where $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of axioms formally defining the mathematical theory, is a tree-like structure whose leaves $A_1, \dots, A_n, A_{n+1}, \dots, A_m$ are either assumptions $A_1, \dots, A_n$ or axioms $A_{n+1}, \dots, A_m \in \mathcal{T}$, and whose root $B$ is the conclusion.  It means that "from $A_1, \dots, A_n$ one can derive $B$, through the axioms $A_{n+1}, \dots, A_m \in \mathcal{T}$", often noted $A_1, \dots, A_n \vdash_\mathcal{T} B$.
Of course, the case $m = n$ means that your derivation never used any axioms in $\mathcal{T}$, and so $B$ is a *logical* consequence of the assumptions $A_1, \dots, A_n$, independently of the theory $\mathcal{T}$.
There is an important technical difference between the assumptions $A_1, \dots A_n$ and the axioms $A_{n+1}, \dots, A_m$: the former can be discharged by logical inference rules such as $\to_\text{intro}$, the latter cannot.

There is an alternative view to deal with formal proofs of a mathematical theory $\mathcal{T}$ in natural deduction. You do not distinguish between axioms in $\mathcal{T}$ and assumptions, all the leaves of the derivation are considered as assumptions (which can be discharged by logical inference rules such as $\to_\text{intro}$). Technically, the tree-like structure of a natural deduction derivation is the same as in the previous viewpoint, what changes is the way you look at it. In particular, with this viewpoint, you lose the distinction between the hypotheses that are used to logically derive the thesis, and the non-logical axioms of the mathematical theory.
Thanks to this lack of distinction, it still holds that proving $A_1, \dots, A_n, A_{n+1}, \dots, A_m \vdash B$ is equivalent to prove $\vdash (A_1 \land \dots \land A_n \land A_{n+1} \land \dots \land A_m) \to B$.

---

In my opinion, using natural deduction or other formal proof systems to prove theorems in a mathematical theory such as ZFC can be of interest in only two cases:

- as a theoretical inquiry as a matter of principle;
- to understand how proof assistants (such as Coq, HOL/Isabelle, Agda, and Lean) work to get verified proofs.

For practical purposes, using natural deduction or any other formal systems to prove theorems in any mathematical theory such as ZFC is a tedious operation that yields very long and almost incomprehensible proofs (even when the theorem to prove is a basic property) where is hard to grasp the mathematical ideas behind a stream of a myriad of syntactical manipulations.
As an example, consider the (almost unintelligible!) natural deduction derivation below that proves the basic fact

$$\forall \forall a \forall b \forall c \, \big( \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c) \big)$$

in ZFC, starting from the following "axioms" (see also a comment at the end of this section):

- $\text{ax}_1$: $\ \forall x \forall y \forall z \, (x \in y \cap z \to (x \in y \land x \in z) )$,
- $\text{ax}_2$: $\ \forall x \forall y \forall z \, ((x \in y \land x \in z) \to x \in y \cap z )$,
- $\text{ax}_3$: $\ \forall x \forall y \forall z \, (x \in y \cup z \to (x \in y \lor x \in z) )$.

So, a natural deduction derivation proving $\vdash_{\text{ax}_1, \text{ax}_2, \text{ax}_3} \forall \forall a \forall b \forall c \, \big( \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c) \big)$ is the following

$$\small
\dfrac
{
 {\displaystyle [x \in a \cap (b \cup c)]^\circ \atop {\displaystyle{{\vdots \pi} \atop x \in b \lor x \in c}}}
 \quad
 \displaystyle{{ [x \in a \cap (b \cup c)]^\circ, [x \in b]^*} \atop
 \displaystyle{\vdots \pi_1 \atop x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)}}
 \quad
 \displaystyle{{ [x \in a \cap (b \cup c)]^\circ, [x \in c]^*} \atop
 \displaystyle{\vdots \pi_2 \atop x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)}}
}
{\dfrac
 {x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)}
 {\dfrac{x \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c) }{\forall x \forall a \forall b \forall c \big(x \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c) \big)}\forall_i \times 4}
 \!\to_i^\circ
}
\!\lor_e^*
$$

where the derivation $\pi$ proving $ \
x \in a \cap (b \cup c) \vdash_{\text{ax}_1, \, \text{ax}_3} x \in b \lor x \in c$ is the following
$$\small
 \dfrac
 {
  \dfrac
  {\dfrac{}{\text{ax}_3}}
  {x \in b \cup c \to (x \!\in\! b \lor x \!\in\! c)}
  \!{\scriptstyle \forall_e \times 3}
  \quad 
   \dfrac
   {
    \dfrac
    {\dfrac{}{\text{ax}_1}}
    {x \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to (x \!\in\! a \land x \in b \cup c)}
    {\scriptstyle\forall_e \times 3}
    \quad { \atop \displaystyle{x \in a \cap (b \cup c)}}
   }
   {\dfrac{x \in a \land x \in b \cup c}{x \in b \cup c}\land_{e_2}}
   \!\!\to_e
 }
 {x \in b \lor x \in c}
 \!\!\to_e
$$

and the derivation $\pi_1$ proving $ \
 x \in a \cap (b \cup c), \, x \in b \vdash_{\text{ax}_1, \, \text{ax}_2} x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)$ is the following (with $B = (x \!\in\!a \land x \!\in\! b) \to  \in a \cap b$)
$$
\dfrac
{
 \dfrac
 {\dfrac{}{\text{ax}_2}}
 {B}
 {\scriptstyle\forall_e \times 3}
 \quad
 \dfrac
   {
    \dfrac
    {
     \dfrac
     {\dfrac{}{\text{ax}_1}}
     {x \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to (x \!\in\! a \land x \in b \cup c)}
     {\scriptstyle\forall_e \times 3}
     \quad { \atop \displaystyle{x \in a \cap (b \cup c)}}
    }
    {\dfrac
     {x \in a \land x \in b \cup c}
     {x \in a}
     \land_{e_1}
    }
    \!\to_e
    { \atop {\atop \displaystyle{\atop \displaystyle{x \in b}}}}
   }
   {x \in a \land x \in b}
   \land_i
}
{\dfrac{x \in a \cap b}{x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)}\lor_{i_1}}
\!\to_e
$$

and the derivation $\pi_2$ proving $ \
x \in a \cap (b \cup c),\, x \in c \vdash_{\text{ax}_1, \, \text{ax}_2} x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)$ is the following (with $C = (x \!\in\!a \land x \!\in\! c) \to  \in a \cap c$)
$$
\dfrac
{
 \dfrac
 {\dfrac{}{\text{ax}_2}}
 {C}
 {\scriptstyle\forall_e \times 3}
 \quad
 \dfrac
   {
    \dfrac
    {
     \dfrac
     {\dfrac{}{\text{ax}_1}}
     {x \in a \cap (b \cup c) \to (x \!\in\! a \land x \in b \cup c)}
     {\scriptstyle\forall_e \times 3}
     \quad { \atop \displaystyle{x \in a \cap (b \cup c)}}
    }
    {\dfrac
     {x \in a \land x \in b \cup c}
     {x \in a}
     \land_{e_1}
    }
    \!\to_e
    { \atop {\atop \displaystyle{\atop \displaystyle{x \in c}}}}
   }
   {x \in a \land x \in c}
   \land_i
}
{\dfrac{x \in a \cap c}{x \in (a \cap b) \cup (a \cap c)}\lor_{i_2}}
\!\to_e
$$

Note that in the usual presentation of ZFC (see for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)), the formulas I called $\text{ax}_1$, $\text{ax}_2$ and $\text{ax}_3$ are not axioms but immediate consequences of more basic axioms. Therefore, the derivations above are actually bigger (and impossible to represent in one page), because they hide the derivations of $\text{ax}_1$, $\text{ax}_2$ and $\text{ax}_3$ from the real axioms of ZFC.

---

For further and more sophisticated details about axioms in formal proof systems (with a slightly different point of view), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711023/288417) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3818869/288417).

Comment: Thank you for the answer which is very informative. Can you please add to your answer a simple example natural deduction proof that uses axioms? You said "In natural deduction, adding axioms means that you add 0-ary inference rules, that is, inference rules with no premises and whose conclusion is one of the non-logical axioms." But I think any inference with no premise leads to a tautology(see my another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837493/is-every-theorem-a-tautology ), however, an axiom is not a tautology, right?

Comment: @William - I added some sentences in several paragraphs of my answer to reply to the questions in your comment, and I added a new final section to give you an example of a natural deduction derivation using some axioms of ZFC.

Comment: i suggest using a fitch or suppes proof format as the proof trees tend to be hard to follow and can take up inordinate amounts of space.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Excellent! I think it is now better than the chapter on this topic  of any logic book I've read.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I would like ask further. The axioms in your answer are so called non-logical axioms, right? When people say a natural deduction system has no or minimal axioms, do they refer to the logical axioms, as non-logical axioms exist in both the Hilbert system and natural deduction systems, and that is why I did not see an axiom in the examples of a natural deduction system in logic books because they just do pure logic deduction, not a proof of a real mathematical theorem like the one in your answer, right?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco But what is the difference between a logical axiom and a  non-logical axiom? Is the former a tautology while the latter is not?

Comment: @William - Right and right (to your last two comments).